# Android Wallet Making for application

Tags: android

I wants to make a wallet in android app where user can recharge it and use it according to work. If user delivers order(as application based on order delivery)his wallet credited and if order not delivered money remains same and vice versa.
Please anyone tell me how can i make it and what to use for this.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: How...?  any clue regarding this

Comment: Online? For students? Enterprise? Java, SQLite for sure

Comment: Anyone can give any clue about wallet making in android....?

Comment: Java, SQL and you you will have to create some backend at server. Nobody will give you more info, because that is not a good question for this site. You didnt show any research effort nor clearly explained your problem

Comment: Thanks for clue #toumash